# count the number of moves within a BST java

Tags: java

I have this code which works fine but is there any way to count the number of operations/steps this program has made? A trace of operations so to say, I need to work out the average execution time(which is the number if int values passed into the program/the number of steps taken to sort out the numbers into order) and need the number of steps information to acquire this? With it being a random number generator I didn't think it was possible but I know there must be a way.

Also I would like to be able to set my root node to a specific number before hand, then add all the random numbers to the root. I don't like asking on here but thought I give it a try.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
    public class BinarySearchTree {


    private Node root; 

    private static class Node {
        Node parent;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        Node( int data ) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString( ) {
            return "" + data;
        }
    }


    public void insert( int data ) {
        root = insert( root, data );
    }

    public Node insert( Node node, int data ) {
        if( node == null ) {
            node = new Node( data );
        } else if( data < node.data ) {
            node.left = insert( node.left, data );
            node.left.parent = node;
        } else {
            node.right = insert( node.right, data );
            node.right.parent = node;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private void swap( Node a, Node b ) {

        if( a.parent == null ) {
            root = b;
        } else if( a == a.parent.left ) {
            a.parent.left = b;
        } else {
            a.parent.right = b;
        }

        if( b != null ) {
            b.parent = a.parent;
        }
    }

    public void delete( int data ) {
        delete( root, data );
    }

    public void delete( Node node, int data ) {

        if( node == null ) {
            return;
        }
        else if ( data == node.data) {
            if( node.left == null ) {
                swap( node, node.right ); 
            }
            else if( node.right == null ) {
                swap( node, node.left );
            }
            else {
                Node minNode = node.right;
                while( minNode.left != null ) {
                    minNode = minNode.left;
                }
                if( minNode.parent != node ) {
                    swap( minNode, minNode.right );
                    minNode.right = node.right;
                    minNode.right.parent = minNode;
                }

                swap( node, minNode );
                minNode.left = node.left;
                minNode.left.parent = minNode;
            }
        } 
        // Continue searching in the left subtree.
        else if( data < node.data) {
            delete( node.left, data );
        } 
        // Continue searching in the right subtree.
        else {
            delete( node.right, data );
        }
    }

    public boolean lookup( int data ) {
        return lookup( root, data );
    }

    public boolean lookup( Node node, int data ) {
        if( node == null ) {
            // Can't find it.
            return false;
        } else if( data == node.data) {
            // Found it.
            return true;
        } else if( data < node.data) {
            // Search left subtree.
            return lookup( node.left, data );
        } else {
            // Search right subtree.
            return lookup( node.right, data );
        }
    }

    public int minValue( ) {
        return minValue( root );
    }

    public int minValue( Node node ) {
        Node cursor = node;
        while( cursor.left != null ) {
            cursor = cursor.left;
        }
        return cursor.data;
    }

    public int maxValue( ) {
        return maxValue( root );
    }

    public int maxValue( Node node ) {
        Node cursor = node;
        while( cursor.right != null ) {
            cursor = cursor.right;
        }
        return cursor.data;
    }

    public void inorderTraversal( ) {
        inorderTraversal( root );
    }

    private void inorderTraversal( Node node ) {
        if( node != null ) {
            inorderTraversal( node.left );
            System.out.print( node.data + " " );
            inorderTraversal( node.right );
        }
    }

    public static int[] generateRandomNumbers( int size ) {
    if ( size <= 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "size must be greater than 0" );
    }
    Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    int[] results = new int[ size ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        results[ i ] = random.nextInt( size );
    }
    return results;
}

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    int[] randoms = generateRandomNumbers( 10 );
    for ( int i : randoms ) {
        bst.insert( i );
    }




    System.out.println( "\n Sorted :" );
    bst.inorderTraversal();

    System.out.println( "\nMax Value:" );
    System.out.println( bst.maxValue() );
    System.out.println( "\n Min Value:" );
    System.out.println( bst.minValue() );

    System.out.println( bst.lookup( randoms[ 1 ] ) );
    System.out.println( bst.lookup( randoms[ 9 ] ) );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply declare a count variable:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
  private int operationCount = 0;
```

And then change the code for whatever operations you want to count to increment this variable:

```
public boolean lookup( Node node, int data ) {
    operationCount = operationCount + 1;
    if( node == null ) {
        // the rest of your code here
```

The only part you have to figure out is exactly which operations you want to count. Then you can change the count inside all of those operations, and check the value of `operationCount` after your program is done.